# "ModuleNotFoundError". How to get my python to identify where the module is installed?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I've installed python on my system (MacOS) using homebrew and I'm using SublimeText as a texteditor to run a simple file.

The code I am trying to run is

```
import matplotlib.py as plt

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
plt.plot(squares)
plt.show()
```

I have installed matplotlib, through running the following code

```
pip3 install --user matplotlib
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MYNAME/pythonprojects/project2datavisualization/mp_squares.py", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.py as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.py'
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u',      '/Users/MYNAME/pythonprojects/project2datavisualization/mp_squares.py']]
[dir: /Users/MYNAME/pythonprojects/project2datavisualization]
[path: /usr/local/bin:“/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin”’]
```

Clearly, my editor doesn't know where to find matplotlib. How do I configure it in such a way so that it does?

Comment: try `ìmport matplotlib` instead of `matplotlib.py` ?

Comment: Damn, I overlooked the simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt". I think you didn't write correctly the name of what you try to import.

Comment: I overlooked the simple solution there, looking for something more complicated than it actually was

Answer (score 1):

In python, we don't add `.py` extension to the imports.

You should try `import matplotlib` instead.

Also, from your code, seems like you want to use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Find more about imports [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).